# Upload multiple images in multiple numbers from multiple fileuploader

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

I have searched a lot but fail to get a appropriate Answer. So, I am again posting this question. Please below picture, where I have 3 file uploader. Each Uploader can upload multiple files. After clicking on the Upload file button all the files should be uploaded into a folder in the application root directory but with a naming convention like ("FileUpload1"-"count") (e.g. FileUpload11) in .Net Framework 3.5

[image]

Also need to store the file names into the DB Table.

Please help in this regard.

Comment: I think the following plugin might help you https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: I already have gone through this link. It can upload multiple files but I also need to upload from other uploaders present in the same page, not only that, i need to get those fileupload controls through code so that I can change file name with the desired names as mentioned above in the question. If my file uploader names are FileUpload1, FileUpload2, FileUpload3 and if they are uploading 2, 3,2 files respectively then the file names will be like FU11,FU12, FU21,FU22,FU23,FU31,FU32 etc...you can follow any naming convention. I have given you an example only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the above question, I spend a quality time and can manage it working flawlessly.

How?

See, in ASP.Net 3.5 has file upload control where multiple file uploading is not possible. But in my case it was like multiple files to be uploaded from each file upload control out of those three.

I haven't used jQuery but followed a different way. I have taken List control, Add Button and Remove Button for each file upload control, now for each time whenever choosing new files, file names is added to the list accordingly for our reference but physical files has been uploaded to a temp folder.

What is the use of this temp folder? - it will check duplicate files, can add files, can remove files if file name is chosen from list and clicked on Remove button.

Now when form Submission or Submit button clicked, all the files from the temp folder will be moved to target folder and temp folder will be emptied.

This is how I have followed.

Will post a article on the same for others to use the procedure or can have different ideas on the same.

Thanks !!